# Objective C wrapper for C library: wrapping calls that return Obj-C objects

Tags: objective-c, c, automatic-ref-counting, wrapper

I'm trying to wrap a C library in Objective C so that I can let ARC handle the creation and destruction of the C objects. Here's my problem... How do I wrap C library functions that return a C object, such as:

```
thing *getRelatedThing(thing *otherFoo);
```

I know that the method signature in Objective-C needs to be:

```objc
@interface Thing {
    @private
    thing *_myThing;
}

- (Thing *)getRelatedThing;

@end
```

It's easy to go from `Thing` to `thing*`, but I'm having trouble figuring out the best way to implement the reverse lookup. I'm not thrilled with the ideas I've come up with so far:

1. Modify the C library to add a pointer back to the Objective-C object.
2. Create a global dictionary mapping C objects to Objective-C objects.

Any other ideas?

Here's a little more context for what I'm trying to accomplish:

**C Library**

```c
thing *newThing();
void deleteThing(thing *ptr);
void doSomething(thing *ptr);
thing *getRelatedThing(thing *otherFoo);
```

**Objective-C Header**

```objc
@interface Thing {
    @private
    thing *_myThing;
}

- (id)init;
- (void)doSomething;
- (Thing *)getRelatedThing;

@end
```

**Objective-C Implementation

```objc
@implementation Thing

- (id)init
{
    if(self = [super init]) {
        _myThing = newThing();
        if(!_myThing) return nil;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    deleteThing(_myThing);
}

- (void)doSomething
{
    doSomething(_myThing);
}

- (Thing *)getRelatedThing
{
    thing *otherThing = getRelatedThing(_myThing);
    return nil; // Need to return a Thing object instead
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done similar thing before and I was using first way. (The C++ library itself support a `void *` user context pointer so I don't need to added it)

But before decide which way to go, you need to be clear how thing works.

1. How does memory management works? Does your ObjC object hold the strong ref to C object or other way around? Make sure you don't create retain cycle.
2. Is one-one relationship between the ObjC object and the C object? If the ObjC object is just a pure wrapper, then you can new a new wrapper every time you need to convert the C object to ObjC object. Since itself does not hold any useful information, they can be discarded and recreated without problem.

---

One possible solution

in addition to your public header

```
// private header
@interface Thing ()

- (id)initWithThing:(thing *)thing;

@end

@implementation Thing

// in addition to your other methods

- (id)initWithThing:(thing *)thing 
{
    if(self = [super init]) {
        _myThing = thing;
        if(!_myThing) return nil;
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)init
{
    return [self initWithThing:newThing()];
}

- (Thing *)getRelatedThing
{
    thing *otherThing = getRelatedThing(_myThing); // assume caller responds to release otherThing
    return [[Thing alloc] initWithThing:otherThing];
}

@end
```

Comment: 1. The Objective-C object would hold the strong reference to the C object. I want the C object to be destroyed when the last reference to the Objective-C object goes away. 2. I'd like to take advantage of ARC to destroy the C objects when I'm done with the Objective-C wrappers. If I always create a new wrapper object, then I can't destroy the C object when the wrapper goes away because there might be other wrappers pointing to the same C object.

Comment: Upon further inspection, the C library does already have a `void *userData` member in the structure that I'm wrapping. Is there a simple way of taking advantage of that pointer?

Comment: thats good news, you can just use `userData` to hold ObjC object. problem solved

Comment: *sigh* Thank you. This problem has been bothering me for a while. Maybe I should have checked earlier.